# StructureMap: Layer-Interface to self-register Implementations

Tags: c#, structuremap

I'm currently setting up an ASP.Net core Architecture with StructureMap. My layers are:

- Api (REST-Connection, Controllers, Security etc.)
- Logic (Application-Layer with the Logic)
- DataAccess (Repository pattern to work with DocumentDB)
- Model
- Common

I would like not to skip layers, therefore the knowledge between them:

- Api knows Logic, Model, Common
- Logic knows DataAccess, Model, Common
- DataAccess knows Model, Common
- Model knows nobody
- Common knows Model

My problem: I register the StructureMap via Scan-Conventions:

```
internal static IServiceProvider ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Configure(
        config =>
        {
            config.Scan(
                _ =>
                {
                    _.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                    _.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IRepository<>));
                    _.WithDefaultConventions();
                });

            config.Populate(services);
        });

    var result = container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    return result;
}
```

My problem, I would like to register some Services on the DataAccess layer as Singletons. But since the  API doesn't know anything about it, I can't tell it here.
My usual approach would be to create a Marker-Interface, load all of them via Reflection and call them, for example:

```
public class ServiceRegistration : Common.ServiceProviding.Initialization.IRegisterServices
{
    public void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<Logics.Integration.Rest.IRestProxy, Rest.Implementation.RestProxy>();
    }
}
```

I couldn't find some out of the box possibility for StructureMap, but since they have added capabilities for scanning Assemblies etc., I guess I missed out some Features, which could make this work, or are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom registry in the DataAcess-layer.

```
public class DataAccessRegistry : Registry {
    public DataAccessRegistry() {
        For<IWidget>().Singleton().Use<DefaultWidget>();
    }
}
```

And then scan for all registries in your scan method with `_.LookForRegistries()`

Comment: Many thanks, this seems like the way to go. One last question: It seems like using Scan on the other Registry doesn't wor out of the box, is that somehow a known limitation?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "using Scan on the other Registry"?

Comment: In the original solution, I justed used scan directly where I created the container, as shown in my post. But when I do the same in my Custom Registry, it doesn't register the IRepository implementions, although it is the exact same Code. Only difference is, that it is scanned from my Custom Registry now.

Comment: Ah, but I thought you were still using the same scan method just adding your custom registries to be scanned as well.

Comment: So is it possible Scan doesnt work the same way, depending if I'm in the Registry or the Root Container?

Comment: Not really, but the context might be different. Meaning you might have different types loaded by the scan method. Hope I'm making some modicum of sense...

Comment: Hm thanks, it seems like I will have to dig deeper a bit. The Registry is on the same Assembly as the Type itself is, so this shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, my original question is more than answered, thanks a lot.